# Mutual authentification using named credential

Tags: authentication

I need to perform 2 way mutual authentification for rest callout using named credential.Under named credential ,I can see a lookup for placing certificate.which certificate can I place under this ?third party or our CA signed certificate.In this lookup I am able to see only our CA signed certificate .If its third party CA signed ,then how can I place it.Could anyone help me on this?
Thanks

---

I have already uploaded 3rd party certificate in mutual authentification section and our certificate in certificate section.My question is about named credentials,in that I can place endpoint and certificate but i don't know which certificate i can place on lookup certificate section in named credential
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Well, You have to contact Salesforce support to enable `Upload Mutual Authentication Certificate` for you.

From Salesforce Docs:

> To prevent security from being compromised by simple impersonation,
>   you can require clients and servers to prove their identity to each
>   other with a mutual authentication certificate.

Steps:

1. On the Certificate and Key Management page, click Upload Mutual
   Authentication Certificate.

> NOTE If you don’t see this option
>       on the Certificate and Key Management page, contact Salesforce to
>       enable the feature.

2. Give your certificate a label and name and click. Choose File to locate the certificate.
3. Click Save to finish the upload process.
4. Enable the “Enforce SSL/TLS Mutual Authentication” 
   user permission for an “API Only” user.

Src: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_keys_uploading_mutual_auth_cert.htm&type=5